# Is didFailWithError triggered when NSURLConnection cancel is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

Is `connection:didFailWithError:` method of `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` triggered when cancel method of `NSURLConnection` is called? If not, how can `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` detect the cancellation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cancel the `NSURLConnection`, none of the delegate methods is called anymore.
There is no need to "detect" the cancellation because you can perform any necessary steps
after cancelling the connection.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm wondering if there is any (preferably official) document that mentions the behavior. Do you know such a technical source?

Comment: @TakahikoKawasaki: See the documentation of the `cancel` method: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/cancel: *"After this method is called, the connection’s delegate no longer receives any messages for the connection."*